# RemoteEndPoint возвращает неверный порт

Tags: c#, tcp

Я создаю подобие серверного приложения с помощью `TCPListener`. Когда клиент подключается к серверу с помощью `TCPClient`, сервер должен определить адрес клиента и отправить ему в ответ определенное сообщение. Попробовал использовать `RemoteEndPoint` для этого, но почему-то порт возвращается совсем другой. Упрощенно, мой листенер выглядит таким образом:

```
TcpListener tcpListener;
TcpClient tcpClient;
NetworkStream stream;
string remoteIpAddress;
string remotePort;
tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(IPAddressPC), PortPC);
tcpListener.Start();
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1500];
String data = null;

while (true)
{
    tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
    remoteIpAddress = ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
    remotePort = ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port;
    Console.WriteLine($"Data came from {remoteIpAddress}:{remotePort}");
    tcpClient.Close();
}
```

В  чем может быть проблема, и как её можно исправить?

Comment: А как вы определили, что порт другой?

Comment: Один из вариантов - грубо привязаться к определенному порту. например 6020.

Comment: https://github.com/MorpheusGod/Server_Client готовый клиент-сервер, может вам поможет

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вы абсолютно правы! А я глупец. Почему-то подумал, что он обязан отправляться с определенного порта. Такое ведь возможно только если мы работаем с сокетами, когда делаем  .Bind() определенного порта?

Comment: @Dude36 Привязывать жестко порт, из которого исходит сообщение, возможно только работая с сокетами? Или такое тоже  возможно отправляя через tcpclient?

Comment: @Ackbar большое спасибо! Обязательно протестирую!

Comment: Да, клиент может прослушивать определенный порт, так же как и все доступные ему порты.